# Python. Is any daemon process manager exists?

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await, celery

I have a python app. It have one infinity loop function, that can called in infinity number of times with any params. Process must starts and stops from web interface.
Now i am using celery for this. 
Web interface starts celery task in current workers pool. But because task is infinity, one function call occupy one worker. It seems bad to start N numbers of celery workers with concurrency param. 
So i have next

- i dont know about memory usage of each loop function.
- i cant find
  a moment, when i should to raise count of active workers, for new
  call of infinity loop function.

What should i do for running and manage parallel processes, and also to get usage statistic of each process? Tornado?
Which strategy i should use?

Comment: Could you detaily explain about `It have one infinity loop function, that can called in infinity number of times with any params.`? It seems like you want to run infinity celery tasks.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar, yes, it is. And task never ended, until stop signal.

Comment: and how many of these tasks do you plan to run?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar, infinity count. I think celery not suitable for that. So i need an any alternative.

Comment: Try to investigate [max_retries](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.max_retries) with `None` parameter.